# Quiet other app's audio on iOS during my app's audio

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app that occasionally has audio instructions (like Google Map's directions). If a person is playing audio (e.g. Spotify) in the background, how can I quiet the background audio until my app's audio is done?

Basically, how do I mimic Google Map's audio behavior when it quiets other app's audio during its own audio instructions?

I've been looking through AVAudioPlayer's docs but not seeing anything:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer

Comment: The term you're looking for is to "duck" other audio. See the [`duckOthers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616618-duckothers) option as a place to get started.

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p643ducking/ch27p912ducking/ViewController.swift Contains some sample code

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession